# Storing and retrieving app icons of all installed apps programmatically

Tags: android, android-package-managers, android-sharedpreferences

I am building an app in which I programmatically collect details of all the apps installed on the device (appName, packageName, appIcon, and some other appDetails).

However, I observe that fetching and storing these app details in a data structure takes a perceivable amount of time. I have tried storing some of the app details using *SharedPreferences* so that I can retain data between different app executions and not initiate a fetch each and every time my app is launched.

Storing the app icons (drawables) however, takes up a lot of space and makes me wonder if there is a more efficient way of retaining the above mentioned app data between app executions, unless of course, new apps are installed after the last time the installed apps were programmatically fetched.

So, my question is, **is there a efficient way of storing app icons (drawables) such that they don't take up too much space**, and at the same time, the app set can be retained between different app executions?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your best shot is saving the list of Apps installed in your App database. You can store the drawable icon of the app as encoded string.

```
String image = getImageFromDrawable(app.loadIcon(pm));
```

where app is ApplicationInfo and pm is PackageManager.

```
public String getImageFromDrawable(Drawable drawable){
    String img = null;
    if(drawable instanceof  BitmapDrawable) {
        Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
        byte[] arr = stream.toByteArray();
        img = Base64.encodeToString(arr, Base64.URL_SAFE);
        return img;
    }
    return null;
}
```

You can then store the details of the app in your application database.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by converting icons to String and storing them in a file using Parceler. To do so,

1. Create an App [POJO](https://synapsetechno.blogspot.in/2016/11/plain-old-java-obect-pojo.html) class with icon as an attribute of Bitmap type
2. Make your class [Parcelable](http://parcelabler.com)
3. Initialize an ArrayList of this class type with all icons to be stored
4. Parcel and store these objects in a file

Now, attributes of type Bitmap are not Parcelable, so you will have to convert them to parcelable type. You may use this function for conversion:

```
static String bitMapToString(Bitmap bitmap) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
    return Base64.encodeToString(baos.toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT);
}
```

And the following function to convert the data back to Bitmap type.

```
static Bitmap stringToBitMap(String encodedString) {
    try {
        byte[] encodeByte = Base64.decode(encodedString, Base64.DEFAULT);
        return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(encodeByte, 0, encodeByte.length);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.getMessage();
        return null;
    }
}
```